# Beeline-Hive returns CSV with blank rows on top of data

Tags: csv, unix, hive, beeline

My script does simple job, run SQL from a file and save to CSV.

Code is up and running but there is odd behaviour while producing CSV output.
Data starts at around line 70, rather then from very beginning in the CSV file.

```
#!/bin/bash
beeline -u jdbc:hive2:default -n  -p  --silent=true --outputformat=csv2 -f code.sql > file_date+`%Y%m%d%H%M%`.csv
```

I would like my data to start at the very first row of actual data.

```
1 blank;blank;blank
2 blank;blank;blank
3 blank;blank;blank
4 attr;attr;attr
5 data;data;data
6 data;data;data
7 data;data;data
8 data;data;data
9 data;data;data
```

Comment: Did you try sorting any of the column values in the table through the query present in `code.sql` file? 
Also, provide the query ran if possible.

Comment: Yes - SQL query has `ORDER BY` one attribute only.

Comment: If you do not want the blank data to come at the top, you can perform the `ORDER BY` in the reverse. i.e., perform `DESC` if `ASC` is in place or vice versa.

Comment: `ORDER BY` didn't work - file still gets created with blank rows on top of my data

Comment: Did you try in both the ways? ```ORDER BY DESC``` & ```ORDER BY ASC``` ?

Comment: Yes. Both `DESC` and `ASC` didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround embedded in next step of my automation:

```
 sed -i '/^$/d' file.txt
```